# localize timestamp in pandas

Tags: pandas, localization

There are some questions about how to localiza a timestamp in pandas, but all of them require the column to be localized to be the index. I don't want that, I want to localize a column, which in not the index, for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'start': pd.to_datetime([1439687730.439, 1439687731.439], unit='s')})
df['start'].tz_localize('utc')
```

this return me an error:

```
TypeError: index is not a valid DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex
```

My goal is to convert the timestamp in my localtime (CEST) using pandas (`datetime` does it automatically).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use [`.dt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.tz_localize.html) accessor as you're operating on a `Series` not a `DatetimeIndex`:

```
In [191]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'start': pd.to_datetime([1439687730.439, 1439687731.439], unit='s')})
df['start'].dt.tz_localize('utc')

Out[191]:
0   2015-08-16 01:15:30.439000+00:00
1   2015-08-16 01:15:31.439000+00:00
Name: start, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

the `tz_localize` method is only available on `datetimeIndex` objects hence the error but it's available through the `dt` accessor